# Alguien me explique cómo funciona este código?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

No logro entender como hacer este ejercicio, alguien me pasó la solución pero no entiendo nada. No entiendo como es que hace el objeto y la verdad me está volviendo loco

```
function masFrecuente(array) {
  // La funcion llamada 'masFrecuente' recibe como argumento un array de numeros enteros
  // y debe devolver el número entero que mas veces aparece (el más frecuente).
  // ej:
  // masFrecuente([1,1,2,3,4]) => 1
  // masFrecuente([3,2,3,2,3,3]) => 3
  // Nota: Los numeros pueden NO estar ordenados
  // Tu código aca:
  const obj = {}

  //cuenta cuantas veces se repite
  array.map((e) => (obj[e] = (obj[e] || 0) + 1))

  let keymayor = null
  let valuemayor = 0

  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop] > valuemayor) {
      valuemayor = obj[prop]
      keymayor = prop
    }
  }
  return +keymayor
}

// console.log(masFrecuente([1, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
console.log(masFrecuente([3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]))
```

Ayuda please! :( (Debo tener 20 caracteres asi que... Hola)

Comment: que no entendes? que hace map? o que hacen los for? me podes explicar que entendiste?

Comment: @gbianchi No entendi por que hace un objeto y tampoco que hace el map, basicamente quiero que alguien me explique como resolver este ejercicio asi aprendo como hacerlo, porque si me dan la solución no aprendo nada

Comment: La forma de aprender a hacerlo, es hacerlo vos mismo. Leiste la documentacion de map? tal vez, la idea no sea usar map en este caso (que te salva de un monton de pasos), si no, hacerlo por vos mismo, inclusive lo que hace map...

Comment: para confundirte mas, map sobre un array, agarra cada elemento, y lo proyecta segun la funcion que le pases.. o sea, esta creando un diccionario usando el elemento del array como clave.. y cero si no tenia valor o +1 al valor si ya existia...

Comment: Un apunte: en ese código el método map no debería ser usando, debería usarse `forEach`en su lugar. O, si queremos ser más puristas, se debería haber usando `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

```
      const array = [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3];
      
      // como  observa  el resultado de la variable repetidos {2: 2, 3: 4}  
      let repetidos = {};
    
      Object.values(array).forEach(function (data) {
        // se encargara acumular los valores repetidos 
        repetidos[data] = (repetidos[data] || 0) + 1;
      });
    
      let keymayor = null
      let valuemayor = 0
    
      for (let prop in repetidos) {
        // se encargara de comparar, que tenga mayor valor repetido, en este caso 3 
        if (repetidos[prop] > valuemayor) {
          // obtiene los valores referentes de la comparación
          valuemayor = repetidos[prop]
          keymayor = prop
        }
      }
    
  console.log(+keymayor); //  resultado 3  que se refiere al valor de la catidad de valores repetidos 
  console.log(valuemayor); // resultado 4  que es la cantidad valores repetidos
```

Answer (score 0):

aquí lo resolví de la manera más descriptiva que pude espero te sirva.

```
// Log to console
masFrecuente([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,2,1,5,6,7,3,1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,2,2,6,8,8,9,3,3,3])

function masFrecuente(numeros){
   //Aquí diccionarioDeNumeros vamos a almacenar el número y sus repeticiones con la siguiente estructura
     /* Toma en cuenta que, el número será la llave y las repeticiones el valor. Un objeto tiene la estructura
     llave : valor
  {
    1: nroRepeticiones,
    2: nroRepeticiones....
  }
   */
  var diccionarioDeNumeros = {}
  var maxRepetido = -1 //Aqui almacenaremos el número que más se repite.
  var auxRepeticiones = -1 //Aux temporal para comprar repeticiones
//Recorremos el arreglo de números
  for (numero of numeros){
    if (diccionarioDeNumeros[numero]) { //Verificamos si el número ya existe cómo llave en el objeto.
      diccionarioDeNumeros[numero] += 1    //Si existe le sumamos 1 al valor que ya poseía
    }else{
      diccionarioDeNumeros[numero] = 1    // Si no existe, asignamos 1 ya que creamos la llave con su valor inicial 1 por su primera repetición.
    }
  }
  console.log(diccionarioDeNumeros) //Acá tenemos cada uno de los números con sus respectivas repeticiones.

//Recorremos las llaves del objeto que hemos creado y vamos a sacar el valor que más se repite y retornarlo.
  for (llave of Object.keys(diccionarioDeNumeros)){ //Obtemos todas las llaves del objeto y las recorremos
  const repeticiones = diccionarioDeNumeros[llave] //Aquí obtenemos el número de repeticiones de cada uno de los números que a su vez son las llaves del objeto diccionarioDeNumeros.
  if (repeticiones > auxRepeticiones ){
      auxRepeticiones = diccionarioDeNumeros[llave]
      maxRepetido = llave
  }

  }
    console.log(maxRepetido)
    return maxRepetido
}
```

Comment: OP preguntaba por el funcionamiento del código en la pregunta, no por un código alternativo.